# Problem with duplicates in distinct when joining

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm writing this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(o.id), o.status,  p.excelID
FROM orders as o
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT(orderId) id,  excelID FROM parcels) as p on o.id = p.id
WHERE o.id is not null and p.id is not null
```

This is example of query records:

| id | status | excelID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **145** | good | 4444 |
| **145** | good | 3215 |
| 94 | bad | 9875 |
| **81** | bad | 5784 |
| **81** | bad | 5631 |

Like you can see i have duplicates in id column even when im using `DISTINCT` function and how can i write question to query to get records like:

| id | status | excelID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 145 | good | 4444 |
| 94 | bad | 9875 |
| 81 | bad | 5784 |

Comment: `distinct` is not a function

Comment: If you want DISTINCT id, status ... then which excelID do you want to see?

Comment: @Josh It doesn't matter which excelID i'm gonna see

Comment: @Piotr then you can remove excelID from the distinct clause to not return anything.  See Mohammad's answer below if you want to pick max or min excelID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase you are interested in maximum value of excelID in case multiple excelID is available. Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(o.id), o.status,  max(p.excelID) as excelID
FROM orders as o
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT(orderId) id,  excelID FROM parcels) as p on o.id = p.id
WHERE o.id is not null and p.id is not null
group by o.id, o.status
```